# How to refactor abstract Inheritance structure into SuperBuilder in Java?

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, lombok, builder

We have a base class

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
  private UserEntity createUser;
  private LocalDateTime createDate;
}
```

And an abstract class which extends this base class:

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity(name = "COMPANY")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class CompanyEntity extends BaseEntity {

  @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private UUID id;

  @Builder.Default
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "companies", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<UserEntity> users = new HashSet<>();

}
```

With two classes extending the abstract class that look like this

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity(name = "SPECIAL")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SpecialEntity extends CompanyEntity {

  @NotBlank
  private String customerName;
  private String somethingUnimportant;
}
```

We have to remove the `@Entity(name = "COMPANY")` in order for the SuperBuilder to work. Our current `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` will therefore no longer work to combine the sub-entities into one table in the database.

**How is it possible to keep the current database structure, but change to include the SuperBuilder constructor?**

Is @jan-rieke around? :D

Comment: Why do you have to remove `@Entity`? What exactly does not work when you have it on your classes?
And what do you want `@SuperBuilder` for? Only for programmatical usage, or do you also use for deserialization?

Comment: We want to change our constructor from new X to X.builder in our inheritance tree, which means we have to implement SuperBuilder and I think MappedSuperclass, since it is an abstract class. We need the Entity on CompanyEntity for the joined db table. Without MappedSuperClass we get "Unique index or primary key violation" due to a constraint on "PUBLIC.ORIGINATION_CHANNEL(COMPANY_NAME)".

We don't current use deserialization.
@JanRieke Thanks for responding, your answers are always great

Comment: It seems you're using JPA/Hibernate. I'm not an expert there, but as far as I know Hibernate does not use builders, so it should not be affected if you add `@SuperBuilder` to your class. I guess there is something wrong with your JPA annotations. Or are you getting errors during compilation?

Comment: Ok this was a great help, yes in the end SuperBuilder was correctly configured after just a few small changes and the error was on the jpa annotations!

For anyone else finding this:
If there are constraint issues, double check that there were not fields that should be unique that are no longer unique due to the conversion process.

Und @JanRieke, danke du bist ne Legende!

Comment: Glad I could help ;)